# Why did I stop receiving data after sending Ctrl-C over telnet from Linux?

Tags: c#, linux, windows, telnet

I have the simplest C# program that reads bytes from a NetworkStream and sends their textual representation back:

```
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;

var listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 5050);
listener.Start();

var client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
var stream = client.GetStream();
int b;
while ((b = stream.ReadByte()) != -1) {
    var str = $"{(byte)b:x2} ";
    Console.Write(str);
    stream.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(str));
}
```

For example, if I telnet to `localhost 5050` and write `hello<enter>`, I get `68 65 6c 6c 6f 0d 0a`.

As soon as I press Ctrl-C in the telnet window, the program echoes `ff f4 ff fd 06` in its console window, but nothing is received by the telnet client. Anything else I enter in the telnet client after that is also echoed in the program's console but is never received by the telnet client. This happens with telnet from WSL2 Ubuntu or from MSYS2.

Native Windows telnet client keeps working fine (and actually sends the data character by character with Ctrl-C represented as `03`).

Comment: Does this still happen if you start WSL2 Ubuntu _without_ involving MSYS2 in any way at all? Does it continue to happen if your server negotiates character-by-character transmission?

Comment: This happens with either client, updated the wording to make it clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're seeing is the interaction of the (linux) terminal with the telnet client and protocol

When you hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> in a linux (including WSL) terminal window<sup>1</sup>, it sends a SIGINT to the forground process running in that terminal.  If that process is a telnet client, it will catch that signal and send a TELNET INTERRUPT-PROCESS command (`ff f4`) to whatever "service" it is talking to (in this case your simple C# program)

When you hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> in a native windows terminal, it just sends a `03` ascii character (ETX).

So to deal with this, you can extend your simple program to understand (some) TELNET protocol commands.  There's a summary of how the protocol works [on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telnet), but it basically just comes down to recognizing 0xff bytes in the input and then doing something based on the following byte or bytes.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>This is the "normal" behavior, though it does depend on the terminal mode.  If the terminal is put into "raw" mode all the special character processing and signalling will be disabled and <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> will just send ascii code 3 (ETX)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is likely due to the telnet client sending a "break" signal when you press Ctrl-C. The bytes you see echoed in the console window (ff f4 ff fd 06) are the telnet protocol commands that are sent to indicate the "break" signal. When you press Ctrl-C in the telnet window, the client sends the ASCII control character ETX (End of Text) which has a value of 0x03. This is different from the Ctrl-C keyboard combination in Windows, which generates the ASCII control character ETX and also sends a SIGINT signal to the running process.

Try adding this to your while loop:

```
if (b == 3) { // Ctrl-C
    Console.WriteLine("Ctrl-C received, terminating connection");
    break;
}
```

Comment: A TELNET BREAK would actually be `ff f3`.  `ff f4` is actually a TELNET INTERRUPT-PROCESS command.  Also interesting is the `ff fd 06`, which is a TELNET DO TIMIING-MARK, which requests that the peer send back a `ff fb 06` sequence to confirm that it has completed the processing of the previous commands (in this case, that it has successfully interrupted the process and is ready for something else)